# Comparing a sequence of fractions with a fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's assume that every *a* belongs to real numbers set and *s* is a sum of all the numbers from *$a_1, a_2...a_n$*. How would you prove this?

$\frac{a_1}{s - a_1}$ + $\frac{a_2}{s - a_2}$ ...+$\frac{a_n}{s - a_n}\ge \frac{n}{n - 1}$

Comment: Can you prove it for two numbers? How about three? What else have you tried?

Comment: are the variables assumed to be positive?

Comment: Yes, they should be positive, I apologize for not mentioning it!

Comment: The question is answered differently here: [Proof for an inequality problem using the rearrangement inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910308/proof-for-an-inequality-problem-using-the-rearrangement-inequality)